# How do I make only *one* specific playlist have "shuffle play order" in foobar2000?

Tags: windows, windows-10, music, foobar2000, shuffle

For many years, I used Winamp. I almost always had the "Shuffle" checkbox checked. Since I switched to foobar2000 about ten years ago, my music listening pattern has changed completely. 99.99% of my songs were never played, because I had to actively search for and hunt them down, putting them in playlists.

So recently, I made one big playlist with *all* songs I have (tens of thousands), and then enabled "shuffle" playback mode. This means it plays a random new song each time I press "skip" or "next". Just like in the Winamp days. Yay.

The only problem is that this appears to be a "global" option, not per-playlist. Which means that whenever I'm sick of playing random songs like this, and want to play one of my small, neatly ordered playlists, it never plays them in the right order. It shuffles. Because shuffling is enabled globally.

If I have to keep turning this on and off manually, the whole scheme falls apart. I just won't be doing that.

Is there some way to set this "shuffle mode" for just my insane "all songs" playlists, while keeping the "correct order" for all the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

> This means it plays a random new song each time I press "skip" or "next"

If you're already skipping songs manually, use the dedicated "Next random" button that foobar2000 has, which gives you a random song even if you *don't* have "Shuffle" mode enabled.

[image: Screenshot of the button in question.]

If it's not present in the toolbar, use "Customize Buttons" and add it from "[main] > File > Playback > Random".

Comment: Well, I never actually click on any of the buttons in foobar2000's UI. I have "global hotkeys" set up in it for F9 (pause/unpause), F10 (next), F11 (mute/unmute) and nothing for F12 because it's already occupied by the frequently used "developers tools" in my browser. So I don't really have any keys to spare, assuming it can even be "hotkeyed"...